# Fatal error cannot instantiate when trying to use http_class with http.php

Tags: php

Am I missing something?
I am trying to use the http.php file in my program, but I keep getting this error:

"Fatal error: Cannot instantiate non-existent class:  http_class in /home/tznius/youtube/btube.php on line 84"

When I examine the http.php class itself (btube.php includes it), I don't see any declarations for the http_class and when I google it, it keep finding references to the http.php file again.

Which files, libraries, etc. am I missing

Comment: The http.php file is in the same directory as my btube.php. I just included it. I didn't mess around with the php library paths.

Comment: Can you post a link to the package you are using? http.php is not a clear indicator, there are dozens of tools with that name.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a prepackaged library, my guess is that your [include path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) needs to be modified to include the library path. Are you getting any warning messages before the fatal error?